# MVC 5 Roles Out-of-the-box

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-roles

Grettings. I see a  thousand of questions and i lost on every one of them... So... Basically i start a new project on VS (WebAPI) with Authentication. I put the token on the header and the methods with

```
[Authorize]
```

works fine. Later i add a two roles into the table dbo.AspNetRoles (admin and users) and to one user i add the relationship in the table dbo.AspNetUserRoles like this:

```
USER ID    |    Roleid
-----------------------
1d156e98-fc8b-4dcb-8dba-f7c66131f488  |  1001
```

So, when i try to put this:

```
[Authorize(role="admin")]
```

Dont work... The request is denied.
What i need to do exactly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So at the end i use this following code to resolve this:

```
public class DAO
{
    public static void addRoleToUser(ApplicationUser user, string role)
    {
        // EL SIGUIENTE CODIGO AGREGA AL USUARIO UN ROL
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext(); 
        var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
        userManager.AddToRole(user.Id,role);
    }
}
```

This sync the role to the user and the context db.
In the controller after register a new user automatically adds the rol "User" with the code:

```
// POST api/Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }
        // Codigo de Ali para agregar el rol "User" al usuario inmediatamente es creado
        DAO.addRoleToUser(user, "User");
        return Ok();
    }
```

Thanks to dawidr to help me to go deep on this.

Answer (score 1):

It's not "Authentication" but "Authorize". Try this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
```

But first you've to create your roles:

```
context.Roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "admin" });
context.SaveChanges();
```

And assign role to the user:

```
var role = context.Roles.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == "admin");
user.Roles.Add(new IdentityUserRole { RoleId = role.Id });
```

Database initialization code can be put anywhere you want, it depends on you:

- when the application starts - check if roles are there, if no then create them
- generate migration and update the migration script by custom role inserts
- put them manually in the database - BUT YOU HAVE TO DO IN PROPER WAY - add roles from the code and check what has been changed in the database

Comment: hahaha... my mistake... sorry... just a type error. The issue persist. Thanks for the observation

Comment: Did you add roles by manual changes in the database? I've updated my answer - try this code...

Comment: If i want to assign automatically a role to any user with this: `var role = context.Roles.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == "admin");
user.Roles.Add(new IdentityUserRole { RoleId = role.Id });` where i must to put in the code? On the controller after the register user code?

Comment: Add them form the code and check what tables were updated in the database. In my opinion you've forgot to update something in the db.

Comment: Ok... but where i must to put this code? on the controller (on the method of my WebAPI)?

Comment: Answer updated once again. Mark as a answer if this helped you somehow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101091/discussion-between-ali-briceno-and-dawidr).

Comment: when i put the code it gives me an error: "The name ''context" does not exists in the current context"

Comment: dawidr i put the code and declare the context, everithing is ok buuuuut..... Don't add the relationship to the db!!!  The code:             `var context = new MVCTest.Models.ApplicationDbContext(); 
            var role = context.Roles.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == "User");
            user.Roles.Add(new IdentityUserRole { RoleId = role.Id });` This returns to me the role id perfect... but dont update the db